# reading USGS Digital Elevation (DEM) data in ArcGrid, GridFloat and IMG formats

Tags: geospatial

The three formats the USGS supports for elevation data are ArcGrid, GridFloat and IMG formats. Does GeoTools read any &/or all of these formats?

Is so, what is there a sample code snippet that shows how?

If not is there something that outlines the procedure for creating my own? e.g which interfaces would I need to implement? I think I need to eventually end up with a GridCoverage instance...but I am new to GeoTools so that may not be correct.

thanks